# How can I prevent an exension div from reloading every time the link changes?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium

I'm currently developing a chromium extension and I'd like to create a fixed div that remains static in the page, no matter what's happening in the rest of the page, so it actually doesn't need to be reloaded every time the user is being redirected to another page.

If it helps, here's my content.js code:

```
createFixedDiv();

function createFixedDiv() {
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
  var bodyInner = body.innerHTML;

  body.innerHTML = `
        <div class='fixed-div-container'>
            This is a fixed div
        </div>

        ${bodyInner}

        `;
}
```

How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not possible, the element must be created each time, but maybe you can use a [sidePanel](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/sidePanel/) instead?